# Adding filter to elasticsearch return nothing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch 7.9 single node instance setup with 0 documents and trying to add a filter by following the [documentation example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) .  When I try to add a filter by issuing a `PUT` on index `my_web` (an index that exists)

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "stop" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get no response from the server.  If I issue a `GET` with `_ml/filters/` it responds showing there are 0 filters.

Do I have badly formed JSON or something?  It's pretty frustrating not to receive any response at all...

Comment: What do you get when running `GET your-index-name/_settings` ? `_ml/filters` are a completely different thing

Comment: @val I get a response showing the index creation date, number of shards, number of replicas, uuid, and version

Comment: Please update your question with the command you run to install your filter and how you're using it in your mappings

Comment: Ah.. thanks.... by doing that I was forced to use curl to verify... and an error message was indeed returned... so my underlying code was not handling the error message correctly.  The response "resource_already_exists_exception" because my index already exists....
I felt the directions implied the filter would be overwritten... I guess I have to delete first

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 issues.

- My application wasn't returning exception errors, so Elasticsearch was indeed reporting an error.  Thanks to @Val in the comments for pushing me on the right track with this
- Once I had this resolved, I could see there was a `resource_already_exists_exception` because the command was trying to add an index that already existed (I thought it would just replace it)

The solution found in [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) `To add an analyzer, you must close the index, define the analyzer, and reopen the index`:

```
POST /my-index-000001/_close

PUT /my-index-000001/_settings
{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "content":{
        "type":"custom",
        "tokenizer":"whitespace"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /my-index-000001/_open
```

Comment: Very nice, glad you figured it out!